# Как через grub! выбрать загрузку системы через usb?

Tags: grub

Как загрузиться (в загрузочную флешку) через параметры загрузчика grub?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала подгружаешь диски

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
```

потом что-то типа этого

```
set root='hd0,msdos1'
linux /путь/linux root=/dev/sda1
initrd /путь/initramfs.img
```

или

```
set root=(hd0,1)
chainloader +1
```

Comment: Мне помог просто метод! 1.Сделал загрузочную флешку 2.подключил к usb интерфейсу 3. Запустил PC (множество раз нажал на кнопку ESC И уменя сразу запустилась загрузоная флешка! МОЖЕТЬ комунибуть поможет!

Comment: значит вопрос сформулирован не так)